# Overriding templates with same name is django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a app named company in django, while both the template directories i.e one in company/templates and the other in base_dir/templates have a file named index.html. when i try to render the templates index.html from company app it renders the template from base directory. I want to override this so that every app uses it's own template directory for rendering. Is there any way by which I can make this possible.
I have added all template directories in settings.py

Thanks in advance

Comment: The usual way is to create subfolders under app templates directories with the same name as the app, i.e. `myapp/templates/myapp/index.html`. You can then refer to that template as `myapp/index.html` to prevent any confusion with root level templates.

Comment: I tried this but I was looking for some way around so that i dont need to change directories of all the css file and images. There are more than 100's of images in my template so it is kind of difficult to go and change directory of every element .

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Templates and static assets are different things. Renaming a template wouldn't and shouldn't affect the URLs of your static assets.

Comment: @AnkitKumar Also in most good IDE's you can write a regex with find and replace if there is a need. Just keep pressing find and replace at correct places.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for the answer I think it should help me in solving the problem